# How can I add layouts to the viewpager

Tags: android

How can I add several layouts to my view pager?(Each layout has a different content)

I only know that I should use Fragment and some stuff, but I'm looking all over the internet and I can't find anything...

Thanx upfront.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you have an example of viewpager: http://viewpagerexample.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/AwesomePager/src/com/geekyouup/paug/awesomepager/AwesomePagerActivity.java